# IDE showing me error on objects keyword in " latest_questions = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:10] "

Tags: python, django, object, model

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/'polls/index.html
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
^polls/ ^$ [name='index']
^polls/ ^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$ [name='detail']
^polls/ ^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results$ [name='results']he current path, polls/'polls/index.html, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not about IDE, you need to properly configure your urls.py page. It seems like Django couldn't find 'polls/'polls/index.html' address. You need to go to urls.py file and add following line;

```
path('polls/'polls/index.html/', views.path_to_function, name='index'),
```